# What can I place inside docker containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, server, containers, devops

I know what's docker and why is it used for, but for example, if I have an app with the following setup: React + Rails + MongoDB + ElacticSearch + more things :)

Should I place each of those things inside a container or what? Because I'm a little bit confused in that part

Comment: Each and every component of your application should be dockerized and use `docker-compose` to create `network` for communication

Comment: the idea behind docker is that each container does one thing and does it well. so each of your components in to separate containers and have them talk to each other in a private network.

Answer (score 2):

Since you add tag `DevOps` on this question.

For production environment, I would recommend to take out of `MongoDB` and `ElasticSearch` from docker containers, which are easily managed by cloud providers seperately and get better performance.

You should be fine to manage `React + Rails` with docker or other docker orchestration tools.

For testing or non-production environments, you can do all in docker.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest writing a docker-compose file where you will define all the services & which eventually will be launched in separate containers.